# Remove icon from SummaryItem

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

i am using an GridControl with a GridView(v20.2.5). I created an SummaryItem in code with the following properties.

```
new GridColumnSummaryItem(SummaryItemType.Count, SummaryMode.Selection, fieldName, Strings.RowsSelected, GridSummaryColumnTags.RowsSelected)
```

Is it possible to remove the blue sum icon? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working by setting the `Icon` to null in the `CustomDrawFooterCell` event.

```
private void GridView_CustomDrawFooterCell(object sender, FooterCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Info != null && e.Info.Icon != null && e.Info.SummaryItem != null && e.Info.SummaryItem.Tag != null
        && e.Info.SummaryItem.Tag.ToString() == GridSummaryColumnTags.RowsSelected)
    {
        e.Info.Icon = null;
    }
}
```